# Align content/navigation horizontally on both ends without flexbox or text-align justify

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, responsive

I'm trying to do in a gist the following :

I have a container with a fixed(hard-coded) width f.x. 1300px and 6 items inside.
The items are anchor tags with a 16px font size ,no width added for them as they do change when the languages on the site get changed.

The task at hand : 
these 6 items need to be aligned on both ends (logo - left , and burger-menu/searchbar - right) here's an example of the html :

```
     <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="navContainer">
                    <a class="navLink" href="">This LongName</a>
                    <a class="navLink" href="">This LongerName</a>
                    <a class="navLink" href="">This evenLongerName</a>
                    <a class="navLink" href="">This short</a>
                    <a class="navLink" href="">ThatShort</a>
                    <a class="navLink" href="">OneWordName</a>
                </div>
            </div>

and the CSS 
`       .wrapper{
            background-color:#CCC;
            color:black;
            height:80px;
        }
        .navContainer{
            width:1300px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        .navLink{
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #676767;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 22px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            margin: 0;
        }
`
```

The problem comes from the fact I cannot use text-align justify with a pseudo element, no flexbox, nothing of the sort to figure out the space between these elements that do not have a fixed width as it will change depending on the content filled in the  tags .

Is it possible to have it aligned both to left and right with the same space without utilizing flexbox/text-align justify or display table, table-cell? The reason behind why I cannot use these it's supposed to be supported on IE8.

Thank you for your time in advance

P.S I tried with getting the width dynamically with Jquery as well, still can't work properly as I cannot exclude the last item to not be in the equation. When it is however it works , though it never adds enough padding-right for the lastchild to stick to the right.

Comment: how about use `position: fixed; left:0 bottom:0;` ...?

Comment: I'm sorry, did you say IE8?  Why stop there, why not IE5? Or lynx?

Answer (score 1):

You mention not using width, but the text will just wrap to the next line(s) if the phrase is too long, so that's how I would recommend doing it. Swap out `display: inline-block;` with `display: block;` on the `.navLink` elements, and add a set width in combination with float since that's supported back to IE8.

You can't use `calc(100%/6)` because it's not supported in IE8, but you can just add in the value of that calculation (16.667%). See included code snippet. I also adjusted the padding on the `.navLink` so it will control the height of the `.wrapper` rather than having a set height on that element. This is because long nav terms/phrases could wrap.

```css
.wrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 100;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.navContainer{
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navLink{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 16.6667%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #676767;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navContainer">
        <a class="navLink" href="">This LongName</a>
        <a class="navLink" href="">This LongerName</a>
        <a class="navLink" href="">This evenLongerName that will wrap to lower lines with more text when necessary like in a German phrase for example</a>
        <a class="navLink" href="">This short</a>
        <a class="navLink" href="">ThatShort</a>
        <a class="navLink" href="">OneWordName</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you couchwood - however i later on solved it using Jquery , where in a for loop i'd go through the links(in the dom) and add paddingToAdd++ (paddingToAdd is a var which is initailly 0) it checks the container width and the summarized outerWidth() of the nav link items and adds +1 padding to all , checks again adds again until there's no more room left in that container's width. 

Thank you once again for your advice however.